# Get sprite boundaries while sprite has an angle

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, jbox2d

So basically i have a sprite that I can move around with it being touched within its own boundaries.

```
    if(v3.x >= spear.b2body.getPosition().x - spear.getWidth()/2 && 
           v3.x <= spear.b2body.getPosition().x + spear.getWidth()/2 &&
           v3.y >= spear.b2body.getPosition().y - spear.getHeight()/2 && 
           v3.y <= spear.b2body.getPosition().y + spear.getHeight()/2 ){

//sprite has been touched
}
```

This works great and i could move it around while onTouchDragged.

BUT If i apply an angle to the sprite, well the boundaries don't follow, they stay the same as if the sprite was still at an angle of 0.

So yeah MATH...  If you can help me out here or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Oh yeah i should also mention that the sprite has a rectangular shape 
(161 x 16)

im using libgdx
imported with box2d

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic geometry, not software development.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found my answer i'm using libgdx didn't see that there was a function that does this already using.

sprite.getBoundingRectangle.contains(x,y)